# Android crashlytics app crashes on launch due to TypeNotPresentException

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

Crashlytics compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') is integrated with the app and is being tested on nexus 7 4.4.4,
The crash is seen from application onCreate method and following stacktrace is obtained. No other similar error/explaination could be found on stackoverflow.
Any suggestions are welcome.

```
  Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com/crashlytics/android/core/internal/CrashEventDataProvider not present
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:290)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.containsAnnotatedDependency(Kit.java:158)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.compareTo(Kit.java:140)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.compareTo(Kit.java:33)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:291)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:153)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:142)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1970)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1864)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:401)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:375)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:332)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:303)
        at com.xxxx.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:19)
```

Comment: problem does not occur on lollipop OS.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently android limiatation of 65K methods is the problem on pre-lollipop devices, the problem is not due to crashalytics library per-se but in general one might run into this problem due to limitation of 65K methods at dalvik level.

Thanks to http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik/ I was able to get the no. of methods in my .apk file.